# Symfony2 Doctrine: set parameter to get query with clausule instance of

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the follow class with single table inheritance:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyProject\MyBundle\Repository\ParameterRepository")
* @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"MidUpperArmCircumference" = "MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\MidUpperArmCircumference", "parameter" = "Parameter"})
*/
class Parameter{
...
}
```

and I am trying to get the instance of MidUpperCircumference:

```
...
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyprojectMyBundle:Parameter');
$discr = 'MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\MidUpperArmCircumference';
$midUpper = $repository->findOneByDiscr($discr);
```

and I have this too:

```
//MyProject\MyBundle\Repository\ParameterRepository

...
public function findOneByDiscr($discr)
{

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
            'SELECT u FROM MyProjectMyBundle:Parameter u 
            WHERE u INSTANCE OF :entity ')
            ->setParameter('entity', $discr);


    try {
        return $query->getSingleResult();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

And I got this error:

> Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in D:\workspace\Project\Symfony2\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker.php line 1727

Comment: Why are you querying by Discriminator? It's only supposed to be used internally by Doctrine. The repository for Parameter entity will only find records that belong to Parameter entity itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the instance of *MidUpperCircumference* object you need to :

```
<?php
use MyProject\MyBundle\Entity\MidUpperArmCircumference

...
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyprojectMyBundle:Parameter');
$discr = new MidUpperCircumference();
$midUpper = $repository->findOneByDiscr($discr);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try setting the data type of your parameter (entity), like this:

```
    ->setParameter('entity', $discr, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::OBJECT);
```